# Flutter: Error with camera and push notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, camera

I have an error in my app flutter with the libraries camera and push notification, when open the camera and in this time arrives a push notification my app close

```
D/SensorManager( 8447): registerListener :: 0, K2HH Acceleration , 200000, 0,
I/CameraManager( 8447): Using legacy camera HAL.
I/CameraManager( 8447): Using legacy camera HAL.
W/Camera  ( 8447): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
F/libc    ( 8447): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 8447 (com.example.app)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j53gxx/j53g:5.1.1/LMY48B/J500HXXU1AOI1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '5'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 8447, tid: 8447, name: com.example.app  >>> com.example.app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    r0 00000000  r1 00000500  r2 000002d0  r3 b6f74074
    r4 b7f32af8  r5 be864e54  r6 000002d0  r7 00000500
    r8 71a72db8  r9 b7a97440  sl 00000000  fp 12fa87c0
    ip 00000001  sp be864e50  lr b6b0fde5  pc b6b1584c  cpsr 600d0030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0002d84c  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::GLConsumer::setDefaultBufferSize(unsigned int, unsigned int)+37)
    #01 pc 000990b5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #02 pc 00284eaf  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: On the phones settings for the app do you enable the permissions for using the camera? Did you add the permissions to the manifest also?

Comment: Are you using: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: Yes, I given the permissions of camera. Also, add into manifest.xml. 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="true" />
I work with plugin permission_handler. The app works fine until I tap on the push notification and I have the camera open.

Comment: I use plugin camera from https://github.com/tengio/plugins, because It has more resolution

Comment: That forked plugin is 2 years old, so I assume quite a bit might have changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Try and work with the latest version, as you seem to be using a forked repo version from 2 years ago.

Use from: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera

Comment: With this plugin reach a max resolution of 1080x1920, I need more high. I used this plugin from pub.dev not from github